# Adding control event methods from the code window Drop downs always go to bottom, can this be changed

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

In the Visual studio IDE, i like to make regions to group functionality.
when I go to add a new code sub for a control event, by using the drop downs at the top of the code window and pick a control event that has not already been added. 
it adds it to the bottom of the code window and I have to copy and paste it to move it back where I want it (at my current caret position).

Is there any way to make these generated control event methods insert at the current caret position instead of the bottom?

To clarify an example would be in the middle drop down box select Button1 in the right drop down box select the Click event.

if this is not a setting does anyone know of an addin that will accomplish this.

I couldn't seem to find a setting for this in the visual studio options (there may be one, but where)

Comment: I have also posted this to the visual studio suggestion board and got a response that they will have a look at it. [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/553179/option-to-add-new-code-methods-at-cursor-not-botto.html?childToView=557724#comment-557724)

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

This is very annoying behaviour.  Would be good to find an option for this, or get it sorted by Microsoft.